# Should I have a separate imports file in Python? What is best practice?

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, python-import

```
main.py:
import sys
import os
import datetime
import numpy
from util import *

util.py:
import sys
import os
import logging
```

1. Is "import sys" and "import os" needed in main.py?
2. Will the script load modules twice if I have "import sys" and "import os" in main.py as well as util.py?

If I create a separate myimports.py file with all the imports for both files, and in both main.py and util.py specify:

```
from myimports import *
```

3. Is each file having to import modules it doesn't need?
4. Should I just keep the respective imports in their place, and not use a separate myimports.py file?
5. If I only need Path from sys, will the script load faster or take up less memory if I use:

   from sys import path  # ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Hard to answer, depends if it's used in `main.py` code
2. No, python import system caches evaluated modules. Once imported, any import statement requesting same module will return it from global registry. There's ups and downs to this
3. If I understand you correctly – this is usually a bad practice (with some exceptions when writing libraries or migrating code with complex backward compatibility). You should treat imports in every module as hint to this modules dependencies – just like parameters in your functions. Cleaner and more explicit they are – easier it will be to read and understand your code. This is main (if not only) consideration you should think in first place
4. Keep imports in modules that use imported functionality. Import wrappers is rather weird idea – it may have some use in rare situations, but in normal day-to-day development it will decrease [true code quality](https://mk0osnewswb2dmu4h0a.kinstacdn.com/images/comics/wtfm.jpg)
5. There is no difference, once you request anything from `sys` (or any other module) anywhere, whole `sys` sill be evaluated and put into module registry. But usually explicit import is really good thing to do – `from sys import path` hints that your module depends on `Path`. Something like `import sys` communicates "I'm depending on `sys` module heavily, so it's easier to import everything at once". In first case, reader expect typical work of fiddling with `PYTHONPATH`, in later one – hardcode system-level "metaprogramming".

   Side-effect of this – as module is imported and cached as whole, after this import is done, any import from `sys` in any other module will be fast (until force reload requested or registry changed manually)

Comment: 1. Wouldn't "from util import *" duplicate the import of sys and os?

- ps. I upvoted your answer, but I don't have the karma to count.

Comment: It doesn't matter how you import and from where - single module will be evaluated once. Once you've imported `sys`, for example, any other code calling `import sys` or `from sys import path` or `from sys import *` - all this things will use cached version. Btw, all this explicit imports is just namespace handling, nothing else

Answer (score 0):

Here's something you might find useful. Sorry I don't have answers to all your questions.

I made this python file directory.

```
python_files
            \main.py
            \my_imports.py
```

In my_imports.py

```
# module to get current time    
from datetime import datetime

current_time = datetime.now()
```

In main.py

```
# import my_imports file from the same directory    
import my_imports as my_imports 

# use my_imports local name to access current_time and then format it. 
current_time = my_imports.current_time.strftime("%H:%M:%S")

# now print to console
print("Current Time =", current_time)
```

Now in run the main.py and it will print the current time to the console. Hopefully this trick is a solution for you.